# flexbox баги, поддержка браузеров и устройств

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox

Привет всем!
Я недавно столкнулся с проблемой flexbox на ios.
Как я понял в итоге не работают некоторые свойства в некорых ситуациях, словом есть баги и исключения.

Например на ios не работала align-items: center; на теге button.

Может подскажите где можно ознокомиться с всеми багами под все и вся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете использовать сервис can i use
Вот пример с вашим свойством: http://caniuse.com/#search=align-items
Там же можно найти ссылки на описание багов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хорошо, спасибо. честно говоря про это знал, но мне быть увернным, что здесь все баги?

например я заметил что в последнем firefox некорректно работала justify-content: space-between; но вроде нет этого бага в списке...

еще заметил тоже в firefox, что.. лучше пример:

<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .div1 { display: flex; }
  .div2 { padding-top: 100%; };
</style>

так вот, padding-top в процентах не работает.. и про это как то не нашел.

Comment: Вы не можете быть уверены, что там все баги. Там все найденные и подтверждённые баги. А сколько их ещё не найденных - чёрт его знает))

Comment: ну да верно, спасибо)